# bash script - supervisor program

Tags: bash, shell-script, vim, users, cron

I have to write a shell-script that have to do the following tasks:
-in every 5 seconds it saves:
       -how many users are using joe and/or vi;
       -if someone was using vi at the last examination, but now he isn't using it anymore, the program should print something about that user and if he is your group that you should send him a mail;
-in every minute it prints:
        -the last minute`s statistics about the usage of joe and vi;
        -the change by the average of usage (increased or decreased);

Any suggestions?

Comment: Really interesting question. If it is no secret what purpose of this script: enforce users to use vi?

Comment: no, it's just a hometask, but I have no idea how to start solving it. I know that scheduling can be managed by using `sleep`, but here I have to schedule 2 main tasks. And there's the infinite loop that I have to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=`ps -ef | grep "joe" |wc -l`  
b=`ps -ef | grep "vi" | wc -l`  

echo `date +"%Y%M%D %T"` $a $b >> somelogfile
```

put them under `crontab`

also, in `/etc/profile` put the something like following:

```
alias vi "vi; mail -s "some message" mailbox"
```

Comment: Hopefully there aren't too many other processes around with names containing the sequence "vi" ;)

Comment: `ps -eo user,comm | grep "[[:space:]]vi$" | uniq | wc -l` (`[[:space:]]` is a POSIX character class, the dollar is regex speak for "end of line")